# How to display CloudKit RecordType instances in a tableview controller

Tags: swift, tableview, instance, icloud, cloudkit

To my knowledge, the following code (or very close to it) would retrieve one cloudkit instance from the recordtype array...

```
    let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Stores", predicate: pred)

    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        else
        {
            if result?.count > 0
            {
                let record = result![0]

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    self.txtDesc.text = record.objectForKey("storeDesc") as? String
                    self.position = record.objectForKey("storeLocation") as! CLLocation
                    let img = record.objectForKey("storeImage") as! CKAsset
                    self.storeImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.fileURL.path!)
....(& so on)
```

However, how and when (physical location in code?) would I query so that I could set each cell to the information of each instance in my DiningType record?

for instance, would I query inside the didreceivememory warning function? or in the cellforRowatIndexPath? or other!

If I am misunderstanding in my above code, please jot it down in the notes, all help at this point is valuable and extremely appreciated.

Comment: Are your outlets hooked up properly?  Can you change them if you were not implementing this code?  If so, just add self.tableView.reloadData().  You are implementing async code your tableView is def loading before the results return.

Comment: Where to start - the code I have posted was taken froma tutoria (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9BJijpVkyE)l I followed.  Unfortunately, instead of simply downloading all the info from icloud, the tutorial allows me to enter the name of an already defined instance and downloads the remaining data of the instance.  However, this is all sey up in its own "search" UIButton.  So I'm mostly wondering where I would enter my predicate/query/record code to be able to create a table with that information.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/cloudkit-introduction-tutorial/ - I'll take a look at this and get back and answer my own question assuming I can pull off the swift to swift 2 conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Without a little more information, I will make a few assumptions about the rest of the code not shown.  I will assume:

- You are using a UITableView to display your data
- Your UITableView (tableView) is properly wired to your viewController, including a proper Outlet, and assigning the tableViewDataSource and tableViewDelegate to your view, and implementing the required methods for those protocols.
- Your data (for each cell) is stored in some type of collection, like an Array (although there are many options).

When you call the code to retrieve records from the database (in this case CloudKit) the data should eventually be stored in your Array.  When your Array changes (new or updated data), you would call tableView.reloadData() to tell the tableView that something has changed and to reload the cells.

The cells are wired up (manually) in tableView(*:cellForRowAtIndexPath:).  It calls this method for each item (provided you implemented the tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:) and numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)

If you are unfamiliar with using UITableView's, they can seem difficult at first.  If you'd like to see a simple example of wiring up a UITableView just let me know!

Comment: Appreciate it!  And for the most part you are spot on; I have a tableview to display the cloudkit data.  It looks like ill need a fetching function as well as the tableview functions.  Now, the user nor I will be making any appends to the recordtype, so will the reloaddata function still be needed?  Also, where would you reccommenf I place the empty array for the future cloudkit data?

Comment: The array to hold the data can be anywhere as long as it is in scope for where you need to call it.  Typically you see it as a class parameter (within the definition of the view/class holding the tableview, but outside any functions.  You only need to call reloadData() if the data changes after the tableView is initialized.  So if the array is set prior to the tableview displaying, then you won't need to call it, but otherwise you will need to.  Since your data is coming from CloudKit, I would assume you would need to reload the tableview after fetching the data?

Comment: although we have numerous concepts at work here, even though I have fetched the data I still need to reload the tableview in order for the array to show?

Comment: When the tableView is initialized, it will call the dataSource methods to find out where to get it's data (which is basically what reloadData() does).  If the data is already there when the tableview is initialized, it will display it.  If you change the data after that (or need to load it from a database) you have to tell the tableview to display the new data ('reloadData()')

Answer (score -1):

First, I had to take care of the typical cloudkit requirements: setting up the container, publicdatabase, predicate, and query inputs.  Then, I had the public database perform the query, in this case, recordtype of "DiningType".  Through the first if statement of the program, if an error is discovered, the console will print "Error" and ending further action.  However, if no run-time problem is discovered, each result found to be relatable to the query is appended to the categories array created above the viewdidload function.

```
var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    func fetchdiningtypes()
    {

        let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "DiningType", predicate: predicate)


        publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }
            else
            {
                for result in results!
                {
                    self.categories.append(result)
                }

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock( { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                })
            }
        }

    }

    fetchdiningtypes()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. Please update your answer to include details about what was wrong and how your answer solves the problem. If you are actually just provided more info for your question, then delete this "answer" and edit your question with relevant details.